# How does SQLITE DB saves data of multiple tables in a single file?

Tags: database, sqlite, b-tree

I am working on a project to create a simplified version of SQLite Database. I got stuck when trying to figure out how does it manages to store data of multiple tables with different schema, in a single file. I suppose it should be using some indexes to map the data of different tables. Can someone shed more light on how its actually done? Thanks.

Edit: I suppose there is already an explanation in the docs, but looking for some easier way to understand it better and faster.

Comment: @mvp, thats what i am trying to do right now. but its a bit overwhelming. so i was wondering if there is an easier article or documentation which i can read to start off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema is the list of all entities (tables, views etc) (the database as a whole) rather than a database existing of many schemas on a per entity basis.

Data itself is stored in pages each page being owned by an entity. It is these blocks that are saved.

- The default page size is 4k. You will notice that the file size will always be a mutliple of 4K. You could also, with experimentation create a database with some tables, note it's size, then add some data, and if the added data does not require another page, see that the size of the file is the same. This demonstrating how it's all about pages rather than a linear/contiguos stream of data.

It, the schema, is saved in a table called **sqlite_master**. This table has columns :-

- type (the type e.g. table etc),
- name (the name given to the entity),
- tbl_name (the tale to which the entity applies )
- root page (the **map** to the first page)
- sql (the SQL used to generate the entity, if any)

  - note that another schema, sqlite_temp_master, may also exist if there are temporary tables.

For example :-

Using `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;` could result in something like :-

[image]

[2.6. Storage Of The SQL Database Schema](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master)

Comment: ok,thanks for the answer.  so the root page is the "page number" from which the data of that particular entity is stored. and using the ```(page size * page number)``` , we can actually read the contents of that particular entity?

Comment: @kartik if you wanted to re-invent the wheel yes you could, typically you let the SQlite interface/API do it on your behalf.

Comment: @Mike_T  Actually, i was trying to understand how a database stores the data. In the process I was trying to make a very simplified version of sqlite, so that I can understand it better, just as an exercise. And thanks for the answer its really helpful !!